# beautifulsoup no unique identifier in table

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I need to get table from page with no unique identifier like unique class. There are multiple tables in that page:

```
...
</table>
</font></td>
<td width="18"></td>
<td width="208">
<table>
    <TD><b>APPLE Smart History</b> Table</TD></TR>
    <tr><td><i><b>Date</b></i></td><td><i><b>Ratio</b></i></td></tr>
    <TR><TD>05/31/1994</TD><TD>3 over 1</TD></TR>
    <TR><TD>01/21/2004</TD><TD>2 over 1</TD></TR>
    <TR><TD>10/28/2008</TD><TD>5 over 4</TD></TR>
</table>
<table width="208" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin-bottom: 18px">
...
```

I need to select table with first column `<b>APPLE Smart History</b> Table`, where APPLE may be random string. So Fixed is `Smart History</b> Table` that should never change.
Other this that is fixed are that there are only two columns in that table with **Date** and **Ratio**.
I need to get date and ratio for each row in this table. Best if I could iterate over rows:

```
for row in rows:
    pass
```

Any idea what is the best selector in BeautifulSoup to get this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to find the `b` element by checking its text (we'll use a [function](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function)), then [locate the first parent](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-parents-and-find-parent) `table` element and then find all rows inside:

```
b = soup.find("b", text=lambda x: x and x.endswith("Smart History"))
table = b.find_parent("table")
rows = table.find_all("tr")
for row in rows:
    # do smth with row
```